# Unable to inject `$http` using AngularJS explicit `app.controller` syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, controller, angularjs-scope

I have [been told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660618) that I should be using the `app.controller` syntax, in order to support minification.

Rewriting the sample (tutorial) example, and I found that I couldn't get it to work:

```js
use 'strict';

/* Minifiable solution; which doesn't work */
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

// phones.json: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-5/app/phones/phones.json

app.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

```js
/* Alternate [textbook] solution; which works */
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}

PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
    {{phones | json}}
</body> <!-- Outputs just an echo of the above line, rather than content -->
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: As far as I know you can use the second version even for minimizing, because of the line .$inject - that tells angular.js the correct unchanged names of the two parameters.

Comment: It works for me. What is the error you got?

Answer (score 13):

The way I did my controller layout is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['controllers', 'otherDependencies']);
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  // your code
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: How to you reference it in the view?

Comment: {{phones}} is correct, since the controller put data in $scope.phones

Comment: You said the 2nd format works, so it must be how you laid out the modules.